# Change default shell to powershell in Neovim

Tags: powershell, shell, vim

Currently the default shell nvim uses is `cmd.exe` I tried changing it by setting shell to powershell in my nvim config but that didn't work, so I tried this command in the nvim command line:

```
:let &shell = 'path/to/powershell.exe'
```

Echo shell command output the powershell path and when I executed `:terminal` it opened a `powershell` tab but after quitting and reopening nvim it was still using `cmd.exe`

How do I permanently change the default shell to powershell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How do I permanently change the default shell to PowerShell?

> Running `:let` ... or `:set` ... will change the settings only for
> that session.
>
> You can paste these lines to your `vimrc` (vim:
> `C:\Users\<username>\_vimrc`, neovim:
> `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim`) to make the change
> permanent. (Reopen `vim` to apply it)
>
> ```
> set shell=powershell
> set shellcmdflag=-command
> set shellquote=\"
> set shellxquote=
> ```

Source: [How do I make neovim use Powershell for external commands? : neovim](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/vpnhrl/how_do_i_make_neovim_use_powershell_for_external/)

See Also:

- [Setting up Powershell as Vim's shell: command does not seem to be passed correctly - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108950/setting-up-powershell-as-vims-shell-command-does-not-seem-to-be-passed-correct)
- [PowerShell with Vim | Robin Douglas](https://robindouglas.uk/powershell/vim/2018/04/05/PowerShell-with-Vim.html)